# Unity ReadPixels in VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl, graphics, rendering, google-cardboard

I am trying the capture the current screen into a texture using:

```
texture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0, false);
texture.Apply();
```

then render it fullscreen directly using:

```
GL.PushMatrix();
GL.LoadOrtho();
GL.LoadProjectionMatrix(matrix); //matrix = Matrix4x4.identity * Matrix4x4.Scale(new Vector3(2, -2, 1)) * Matrix4x4.Translate(new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0));
Graphics.DrawTexture(rect, texture, mat); //rect = new Rect(0, 0, 1, 1);
GL.PopMatrix();
```

This works perfectly when testing on desktop however when building for VR (google cardboard) on Android, the texture is distorted. My guess the culprit is the VR SDK projection matrix, so I looked into [Camera.SetStereoProjectionMatrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.SetStereoProjectionMatrix.html). Setting these however don't seem to affect anything.

I tried the second part of the code using a predefined texture which rendered fine on the device, so that narrows it down to the capturing phase.

Could anyone shed a light on this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Only half of the texture being filled, it suddenly occurred to me that in VR each eye needs to be rendered seperately. I'm not familiar enough with this pipeline but the first thing I tried was to use the RenderTexture size instead of the Screen size when creating a new Texture and BAM! Apparently I was allocating the wrong (double) size for my texture making it appear squished when rendering.

```
RenderTexture curr = RenderTexture.active;
RenderTexture.active = Camera.main.activeTexture;
texture = new Texture2D(curr.width, curr.height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
texture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, curr.width, curr.height), 0, 0, false);
texture.Apply();
RenderTexture.active = curr;
```

I will probably still need to account for the 2 different eyes and thus capture 2 textures but that's another adventure, cheers!